# Singular points on cubic curves

Tags: algebraic-geometry, solution-verification, elliptic-curves, cubics

I am trying to prove the following claim:

> Let $K$ be a field and let $f \in K[x]$ be a monic cubic polynomial. Define the cubic curve $C: y^2 = f(x)$. If $C$ has a singularity $(a, b)$, then $b = 0$ and $a$ is a solution to $f(x) = 0$.

I feel like I have a proof, but I'm not sure if it is correct because I feel that it is too simple.

*Proof.* Write $f(x) = x^3 + ax^2 + bx + c$ where $a, b, c \in K$ and consider the polynomial $P(x, y) = y^2 - f(x)$ which defines the curve $C$. Suppose $(p, q)$ is a singularity of $C$. Then this implies that
$$
\frac{\partial P}{\partial y}(p, q) = 2q = 2 \sqrt{f(p)} = 0.
$$
It thus follows that $q = 0$ and $f(p) = 0$. $\, \, \blacksquare$

Would you agree that this is a proof? If not, can you point out where the error is? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks correct to me--although I'd avoid reusing the variables $a, b$.  Also $P(x)$ should be $P(x, y)$.

Comment: I agree with the poor labelling, I will make an edit. Thank you for your feedback.

Comment: Actually, (p,q) is a singular point if and only if q=0 and f(p)=f'(p)=0. The proof is the same.

Comment: The conclusion is correct, but the converse is not - otherwise any cubic curve would be singular over $\mathbb C$! Rather $f$ needs to have a double root. In the proof, where does $\sqrt{f( p)}$ come from? Shouldn't that be $\frac{df}{dx} (p)$?

Comment: @Mathmo123 The $\sqrt{f(p)}$ term comes from the relation $y^2 = f(x)$. Since $(p, q)$ is a point on $C$, then $q^2 = f(p)$.